# Excel - Keep data on field that starts with

Tags: text-processing

I have an excel file with the following data example

```
1   E   Eastland Care Ctr   pbrotherton@voa.org 2425 Kimberly Pkwy E    Columbus    OH  43232-4271  2072822617  6148689306  805101  Nursing & Convalescent Homes    www.voa.org
4   S   Softworks Inc   nuttfive@aol.com    8185 Pickerington Rd    Canal Winchester    OH  43110-8895  6148640194  6148371639  573401  Computer Software   www.softworks.org
5   F   First Apostolic Church-Dublin   hwinmain@yahoo.com  6477 Eiterman Rd    Dublin  OH  43016-8727  7166310257  6147665964  866107  Churches    www.murak.com
```

On the 11th field you see `805101` for the first line. I only want to keep data from this file that starts with 80-85 for this field. The number could be `80 820 8036` or `84000` but they must always start with either `80 81 82 83 84 85`

Comment: `perl` and `python` can read an `excel` file, check this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/reading-an-microsoft-excel-file) or search google

Comment: Which format is the excel file, .csv? What tools do you have to parse it, if not? Excel isn't available for Unix or Linux, is it?

Comment: that's why i posted a comment about `perl` and `python`, because they can parse excel files and are certainly *nix tools